# How to show all days from an dates interval HTML PHP

Tags: php, html, date

i am facing a problem when i want to show day by day from an interval of dates.

What i mean is that i have a simple form:

```
<form method="post" action="">
From Date1: <input type="text" name="date1" value="<!--10 days ago date (2013-09-14)-->"/>
<br>
To Date2: <input type="text" name="date2" value="<!--today's date (2013-09-24)-->"/>
<input type="submit" value="Change interval"/>
</form>
```

From this form i get two date and i would like to show all the days between those, like this:

```
| 2013-09-14

| 2013-09-15

| 2013-09-16

| 2013-09-17

| .

| .

| 2013-09-24
```

And if it possible save all this dates in Array or variable.

Hope you can help me. Thanks you.

Comment: can u post what u try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$start    = new DateTime('2013-09-01');
$end      = new DateTime('2013-09-30');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $dt)
{
    echo $dt->format("Y-m-d") . PHP_EOL;
}
```

**[See it in action](http://3v4l.org/a1mTS)**

Specifically for your use case:

```
$dates    = array();
$start    = new DateTime($_POST['date1']);
$end      = new DateTime($_POST['date2']);
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $dt)
{
    $dates[] = $dt->format("Y-m-d");
}
```

Comment: This is a much better answer than what I provided. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 1):

Try this, think I got it from php.net years ago, sorry don't have a better reference link...

```
function dates_array($start, $end) {
    $range = array();   

    if (is_string($start) === true) $start = strtotime($start);
    if (is_string($end) === true )  $end = strtotime($end);

    do {
        $range[] = date('Y-m-d', $start);
        $start = strtotime("+ 1 day", $start);
    }
    while($start <= $end);

    return $range;
}
```